# Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver in spring

Tags: java, oracle, maven, spring-boot, gradle

I downloaded oracle db (Express Edition) and am able to establish a connection to it with my sql developer

Here is my application.properties-file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.data-username=sys
spring.datasource.data-password=oracle
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8090
```

I downloaded ojdbc6.jar and installed it into maven in order to use it in my gradle file:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=Downloads\Programmieren\OJDBC\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

compile-command in gradle:

```
compile ("com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.4")
```

Here is the error I get:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

EDIT:
This was solved by setting the M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME variable!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by setting the M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME system-variable and by telling gradle to use the local maven repo with "mavenLocal()"

Answer (score 1):

use spring.datasource.jdbc-url instead of spring.datasource.url

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you forget to tell gradle to use local maven repo? Like below

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: can I have mavenLocal() and mavenCentral() simultaneously?

Comment: and yes, I don't have mavenLocal, I just have mavenCentral

Comment: @watchme yes you can have multiple repositories

Comment: The driver is saved under C:\Users\josh\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc6

But gradle cannot find it.